# How to do a GET with Android on a Spring Backend

Tags: android, json, spring, get

My backend is running Spring Boot. I need to hit this URL

```
localhost:8080/api/v1/animals
```

The result will be a Json file.

From my Android app I am trying to get all those Animals. This is what I am trying:

```
public class AnimalsTask extends AsyncTask
{
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects)
    {
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        rest.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        String result = rest.getForObject("http://localhost:8080", String.class, "/api/v1/animals");

        return null;
    }
}
```

This gives me an error:

> GET request for "http://localhost:8080": failed to connect to
>   localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED
>   (Connection refused);

Can I test from my Android phone while running the Spring web app on my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I test from my Android phone while running the Spring web app on my computer?

Yes of course you can, make sure you are on the same WiFi.

One important thing you have to do is go to `Terminal` put `ipconfig` and get your IP from there, and then from the device or from your Android Studio just change the `localhost` to `yourIP:8080`

So your `BASE_URL` should be something like this :

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.171:8080/";
```

> Sure, can you show me how the code would look for my case?

Sure!

First of all add this in your `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
```

Then create a class called `ApiClient`

class APIClient {

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
static Retrofit getClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.176:8080/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

Then create another class called `APIInterface`

```
interface APIInterface {
  @GET("/api/v1/animals")
  Call<YOURPOJOCLASS> getAnimals();
```

YOURPOJO class can be done using this [`jsonschema2pojo`](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) selecting `GSON` and in `Preview` you can copy and paste your pojo class.

Then the way you call it is as easy as this :

```
APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);

Call<YOURPOJOCLASS> call = apiInterface.getAnimals();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<YOURPOJOCLASS>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<YOURPOJOCLASS> call, Response<YOURPOJOCLASS> response) {

                YOURPOJOCLASS pojoclass = response.body();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserList> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
```

Hope it's clear how to implement it!

Comment: I used the IP but I got this error now: `GET request for "http://192.168.0.176:8080" resulted in 404 (); invoking error handler`. By the way, if I use Postman tool I can hit the GET api.

Comment: I recommend you to use Retrofit, are you able to use Retrofit? It's easy and I can show you how to

Comment: Sure, can you show me how the code would look for my case?

Comment: Thank you, very helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `localhost` use the IP address of your pc. First make sure your android device and PC are on the same network. You can do this by simply connecting your PC to your mobile hotspot. Then run command `ipconfig` in windows or `ifconfig` in linux. Get your device IP from there and use that in your android code. Also learn the basics as `localhost` means the loopback address of your device.